# Using django templates to generate django templates

Tags: django, templates

How can I use django templates to generate django templates? Is there a way to escape the template mark-up? Like %% for % in pythons string.

Comment: could you plz eleborate your requirement ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the new [Verbatim template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) (Django 1.5)